# fine db comparer program for mysql

Tags: mysql, synchronization, comparison

Working with MSSQL, I have several tools I use to compare DB structure and data, like SQL-compare, SQL-delta, SQL-Clarity Effects, etc...

Is there some equivalent program for MySQL???

I need a program that can show me differences and, if possible, prepare the synchronize scripts...

If it's free it would be better...

Answer (score 1):

[SYNC DATABASE](http://www.spectralcore.com/syncdatabase/features.php) you can use the trial

[EMS Data Comparer 2007 for MySQL](http://terrificsoft.com/business/databases-tools/ems-data-comparer-for-mysql.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Navicat for MySQL](http://www.navicat.com/) - trial available. Quite good for MySQL management

Answer (score 1):

Check out Devart's database compare tools for MySQL:

- [dbForge Schema Compare for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/schemacompare/)
- [dbForge Data Compare for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/datacompare/)

They are not free tools, but still quite affordable and have 30-days free trial period.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [mysqldiff](http://www.adamspiers.org/computing/mysqldiff/), which is free.  I haven't used it yet myself, but I'm planning to try it out.